# Show that the following set has measure 0

Tags: lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a strictly increasing and absolutly continous function with $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$. Let $H=\{x: g'(x) \neq 0\}$ and $E \subseteq [c,d]$ with $|E|=0$. Show that $|g^{-1}(E) \cap H|=0$.

I want to check if this is fine or not

The previous exercise was to show that if $G \subseteq[c,d]$ was open then $\int_{g^{-1}(G)}g'(x)dx=|G|$ and I've done it.

So, what I was thinking is that given some $\epsilon > 0$ I can take a set $G=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}G_n$ with $G_n=(c_n, d_n)$ such that $E \subseteq G$ and $|G| < \epsilon$, so, since $g$ is absolutely continous and biyective (because is strictly incresing) then exists a $\delta_\epsilon >0$ such that $\sum g^{-1}(d_n)-g^{-1}(c_n)<\delta_\epsilon$ and $\delta_\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ because is a strictly incresing function.

Is this ok? I'm bothered by the fact that I don't use the set $H$ at all and a little bit because I don't use the previous part either.

Thanks

Comment: how did you deduce that : "then exists a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $\sum g^{-1}(d_n)-g^{-1}(c_n)<\delta_\epsilon$ and $\delta_\epsilon \to 0$ when $\epsilon \to 0$"?

Comment: I don't think the inverse of an absolutely continuous function needs to be absolutely continuous. So you cannot conclude that $\sum g^{-1}(d_n) - g^{-1}(c_n) < \delta_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Because it's absolutley continous. Since $\sum d_n - c_n = \sum g(b_n) - g(a_n) < \epsilon$ then exists $\delta$ such that $\sum b_n - a_n < \delta$. Is this correct?

Comment: No. If $g$ is absolutely continuous, the following is true. For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, so that whenever $\sum d_n - c_n < \delta$, then $\sum g(d_n) - g(c_n) < \epsilon$. You are concluding the opposite direction, which you cannot do unless $g^{-1}$ is also absolutely continuous. (Also, you can only do this for a finite set of disjoint intervals, not a countable set).

Comment: You're right. I got it backwards. Thanks! Any idea on how this is proved? This was the best I got

Comment: Perhaps you could try showing that $|g^{-1}(E) \cap H_n| = 0$ where $H_n = \{x |g'(x) \ge { 1\over n} \}$?

Answer (score 1):

What your wrote at your argument its not always true, even if both $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are absolutely continuous functions. For example take $g(x)=x^2$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$. Then both $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are strictly increasing, hence both are absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Now consider the intervals $$[\alpha_n,\,\beta_n]=\biggl[\frac{1}{2n},\,\frac{1}{n}\biggr]$$

Then, $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{2n})=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{4n^2}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Hence, the tails, $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f(\beta_k)-f(\alpha_k)\sim \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\to 0$ as $N\to \infty$. But on the other hand,
$$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\beta_n-\alpha_n=\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}=\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}=\infty$$
Which means that for every $\epsilon>0$ you can find large $N$ such that
$$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)<\epsilon$$
but you always have $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}(\beta_n-\alpha_n)=\infty$. Now, to answer your question since you have proved that
$$\tag{1} \int_{g^{-1}(G)}g'(x)\,dx=|G|$$
you can use this to prove that $|g^{-1}(E)\cap H|=0$. First observe that since $g$ is strictly increasing, then $g'(x)\geq 0$ almost everywhere. Using $(1)$ for $G=E$ we get
$$\int_{g^{-1}(E)}g'(x)\,dx=|E|=0$$
On $H^c$ we have $g'(x)=0$, hence
\begin{align}
\int_{g^{-1}(E)}g'(x)\,dx&=\int_{g^{-1}(E)\cap H}g'(x)\,dx+\int_{g^{-1}(E)\cap H^c}g'(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{g^{-1}(E)\cap H}g'(x)\,dx=0
\end{align}
Now since on $g^{-1}(E)\cap H$ we have that $g'(x)>0$ we deduce that $|g^{-1}(E)\cap H|=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that might be something missing, because (1) is valid only for open sets. Probably there is some argument that lets me go from open sets to sets like the one you've put.

Comment: One more question. Is the last part neccesary? Couldn't I say that since $g^{-1}(E) \cap H \subseteq g^{-1}(E)$ and $g'(x) > 0$ ae then $0 \leq int_{g^{-1}(E) \cap H} g'(x)dx \leq \int_{g^{-1}(E)} g'(x)dx = 0$?

Comment: @Silkking Yes your are right. I should have said something about using $(1)$ for arbitrary measurable $A\subseteq [c,d]$. First observe that you can prove that $(1)$ holds for closed sets. Then take an arbitrary measurable $A\subseteq [c,d]$ and by the regularity of the measure you can find $F\subseteq A\subseteq G$ with $F$ closed, $G$ open and $\mu(G)=\mu(A)=\mu(F)$. Now using these facts you can prove that $(1)$ holds also for $A$. For your last question the answer is yes, you can proceed as you said.